Error from concurrently reading from MYSQL database
I have a flask program. On the get method for '/' route, python code accesses the MYSQL database with the following
""" returns cash of current user """
def returncash(argdb):
    argdb.execute("SELECT cash FROM fin_users WHERE id = %s", (session['user_id'],))
    row = argdb.fetchall()

    return row[0]['cash']


This works most of the time. However if in my browser I reload the page twice quickly on the '/' route, the program hangs. I've narrowed it down to this line
argdb.execute("SELECT cash FROM fin_users WHERE id = %s", (session['user_id'],))

Seems like its trying to access the same records at the same time and freezing? There are no error messages, it just never gets to the next line. If I hit refresh a couple more times I get the following error
ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\myPrograms\financePlus\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1473, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\myPrograms\financePlus\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 882, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\myPrograms\financePlus\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 880, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\myPrograms\financePlus\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 865, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\myPrograms\financePlus\landf.py", line 12, in innerFunction
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\myPrograms\financePlus\app.py", line 31, in index
    cash = func.returncash(db)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\myPrograms\financePlus\func.py", line 37, in returncash
    argdb.execute("SELECT cash FROM fin_users WHERE id = %s", (session['user_id'],))
  File "E:\myPrograms\financePlus\venv\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 551, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\myPrograms\financePlus\venv\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 490, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\myPrograms\financePlus\venv\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 404, in _handle_result
    columns[i] = self._protocol.parse_column(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\myPrograms\financePlus\venv\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\protocol.py", line 239, in parse_column
    (packet, _) = utils.read_lc_string(packet)  # db
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\myPrograms\financePlus\venv\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\utils.py", line 199, in read_lc_string
    if buf[0] == 251:  # \xfb
       ~~~^^^
IndexError: bytearray index out of range

Not too sure what I can do to resolve this. Any help is appreciated! Sorry I am pretty new to programming, hope this all makes sense
I tried adding a lock table to the record on the read, as I thought maybe that was what was causing the issue
""" returns cash of current user """
def returncash(argdb):

    argdb.execute("LOCK TABLES fin_users READ")
    argdb.execute("SELECT cash FROM fin_users WHERE id = %s", (session['user_id'],))
    row = argdb.fetchall()
    argdb.execute("UNLOCK TABLES")

    return row[0]['cash']


but I got the following error
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
[2024-05-21 14:25:39,567] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\myPrograms\financePlus\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1473, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\myPrograms\financePlus\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 882, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\myPrograms\financePlus\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 880, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\myPrograms\financePlus\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 865, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\myPrograms\financePlus\landf.py", line 12, in innerFunction
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\myPrograms\financePlus\app.py", line 31, in index
    cash = func.returncash(db)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\myPrograms\financePlus\func.py", line 37, in returncash
    argdb.execute("SELECT cash FROM fin_users WHERE id = %s", (session['user_id'],))
  File "E:\myPrograms\financePlus\venv\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 551, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\myPrograms\financePlus\venv\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 490, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\myPrograms\financePlus\venv\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 384, in _handle_result
    elif packet[4] == 0:
         ~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: bytearray index out of range

====================== EDIT ====================
Following @shadow's suggestion I tried updating my mysql.connector using
python -m pip install mysql-connector-python
It was successful.
Then ran the program again, double clicking the page refresh at '/' route. This time the program did not freeze but immediately had the following error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\myPrograms\financePlus\venv\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 697, in cmd_query
    self._cmysql.query(
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Lost connection to MySQL server during query

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\myPrograms\financePlus\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1473, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\myPrograms\financePlus\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 882, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\myPrograms\financePlus\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 880, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\myPrograms\financePlus\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 865, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\myPrograms\financePlus\landf.py", line 12, in innerFunction
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\myPrograms\financePlus\app.py", line 31, in index
    cash = func.returncash(db)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\myPrograms\financePlus\func.py", line 35, in returncash
    argdb.execute("SELECT cash FROM fin_users WHERE id = %s", (session['user_id'],))
  File "E:\myPrograms\financePlus\venv\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py", line 372, in execute
    result = self._cnx.cmd_query(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\myPrograms\financePlus\venv\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\opentelemetry\context_propagation.py", line 102, in wrapper
    return method(cnx, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\myPrograms\financePlus\venv\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 705, in cmd_query
    raise get_mysql_exception(
mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
127.0.0.1 - - [22/May/2024 16:31:08] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 - ```


Will continue to try with another alternative connector


You do not need to lock your tables when you issue a select statement - mysql can perform non-locking reads concurrently without any problem. The error seems to come from whatever mysql connector you are using, not from mysql. You may have to change your mysql connector version.

If you encounter if buf[0] == 251:  # \xfb in 2024, update mysql connector to the latests version. Pro tip: package name should be mysql-connector-python, for some reason, I've used mysql.connector.
